# chmod 500 on a directory but owner can still create files?

Tags: linux, permissions

I created a directory `x` and changed its permissions with `chmod 500 x`. If I try running `touch x/file` that works perfectly fine, no permission denied error. How is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you are using root user

```bash
whoami
```

The root user has God privileges.